# Is there a way in R to compare the layers of a multidimensional array at each row-column index to identify the max value

Tags: r, arrays

I'm struggling to figure out how to compare the layers of a multidimensional array at the each row-column index to identify which layer has the maximum and minimum value for each of those locations.  In practice, the array may end up having dozens if not more layers.  But suppose I have a 3 x 3 x 3 array as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
test <- array(c(rnorm(1:5), rnorm(1:5), rnorm(1:5)), dim=c(3,3,3), dimnames = list(
  c("Row1", "Row2", "Row3"),
  c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3"),
  c("Array1", "Array2", "Array3")
  ))
```

I need to generate a matrix or other output that tells me which layer has the highest value at Row1-Col1, Row1-Col2, Row1-Col3, ...

Ideally it would be a matrix in a form similar to this (not the correct results, just the format):
[image: A 2-D Matrix with the same x and y dimensions as the original matrices but with values drawn from the names of the different array layers]

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `apply` the `which.max` function over the two other dimensions:

```r
apply(test, c(1, 2), which.max)
#>      Col1 Col2 Col3
#> Row1    3    1    1
#> Row2    2    3    3
#> Row3    2    2    1
```

Where each number indicates the layer with the maximum value.

If you really want the *name* of the correct "slice", you can do:

```r
apply(test, c(1, 2), function(x) dimnames(test)[[3]][which.max(x)])
#>      Col1     Col2     Col3    
#> Row1 "Array3" "Array1" "Array1"
#> Row2 "Array2" "Array3" "Array3"
#> Row3 "Array2" "Array2" "Array1"
```

We can confirm these are correct visually:

```r
test
, , Array1

           Col1       Col2      Col3
Row1 -0.6264538  1.5952808 0.4874291
Row2  0.1836433  0.3295078 0.7383247
Row3 -0.8356286 -0.8204684 0.5757814

, , Array2

           Col1       Col2       Col3
Row1 -0.3053884 -0.6212406 -0.6264538
Row2  1.5117812 -2.2146999  0.1836433
Row3  0.3898432  1.1249309 -0.8356286

, , Array3

           Col1      Col2       Col3
Row1  1.5952808 0.4874291 -0.3053884
Row2  0.3295078 0.7383247  1.5117812
Row3 -0.8204684 0.5757814  0.3898432
```

Comment: This is great! I should be able to use a vector of the original array names to swap out the values with names. Thanks!